# Distinguishing between although and while

Tags: vocabulary, conjunctions, ambiguity

What are some circumstances in which "although" and "while" are semantically interchangeable? When are they not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example:

**While we would like to accommodate your request, we have no vacancies.

Although we would like to accommodate your request, we have no vacancies.**

But we cannot simply reverse the sentence with "while" as we can with "although":

OK:  **We have no vacancies, although we would like to accommodate your request.**
NOT OK: **We have no vacancies, while we would like to accommodate your request.**

The concession clause of that type must introduce the sentence if you wish to use "while".

Yet when a comparison is being set up,  *while" introducing the sentence means "on the one hand":

**While [on the one hand] the emu is flightless, the hawk flies very swiftly indeed.**

and when "while" connects the two clauses, it means "on the other hand":

**The hawk flies very swiftly indeed, while [on the other hand] the emu is flightless.**

"Although" could be substituted for "while" in both of those sentences.